# Javascript JQuery Gradual reveal an image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a leap year function, and I want it to slowly reveal an answer and then slowly fade away after a period of time. Here's my code.

```
function isLeaper() {
            var image1 = '../images/yes.png';
            var image2 = '../images/no.png';
            var year = document.getElementById("isLeaper").value;
            var arr = year.split('/');
            var splitYear = arr[arr.length - 1];
            // 1. If the year is divisible by 4, but not 100.
            if ((parseInt(splitYear) % 4) == 0) {
                if (parseInt(splitYear) % 100 == 0) {
                    if (parseInt(splitYear) % 400 != 0) {
                        $('#myDiv').html(year + 'is not a leap year. Sorry!').fadeIn('normal', function() {
                            $(this).fadeOut();
                        });
                        // alert(year + 'is not a leap year. Sorry!');
                        return "false";
                    }
                    if (parseInt(splitYear) % 400 == 0) {
                        $('#myDiv').html(year + 'is a leap year. Hooray!').fadeIn('normal', function() {
                            $(this).fadeOut();
                        });

                        //alert(splitYear + ' is a leap year. Hooray! ');
                        return "true";
                    }
                }
                if (parseInt(splitYear) % 100 != 0) {
                    $('#myDiv').html(year + 'is a leap year. Hooray!').fadeIn('normal', function() {
                        $(this).fadeOut();
                    });

                    //alert(splitYear + ' is a leap year. Hooray! ');
                    return "true";
                }
            }
            if ((parseInt(splitYear) % 4) != 0) {
                $('#myDiv').html(year + 'is not a leap year. Sorry!').fadeIn('normal', function() {
                            $(this).fadeOut();
                        });

                //alert(splitYear + ' is not a leap year. Sorry! ');
                return "false";
            }
        }

        if ((parseInt(year) % 4) != 0) {
            alert(year + ' is not a leap year. Sorry!');
            return "false";
        }
```

I've declared a div in the html portion, but nothing is happening. It's set to reveal an answer, and I also want to modify the yes answers to reveal the image yes.png and the no answers to reveal the no.png images. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For `fadeIn` your `div` must be `hidden`

Add in **CSS**

```
#myDiv
{
    display:none;
}
```

Then try.

Also Read for `fadeIn` http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Answer (score 0):

I do something like:

```
$('#myDiv').html(year + 'is a leap year. Hooray!').fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
```

Also @Rohan mentions a good point. The div should be see to display: hidden in css.